# .htaccess mod_rewrite not consistent

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is a sample from my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^login/?$           loginregister.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register/?$        loginregister.php [L]
RewriteRule ^member/([^/]*)$    member.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^members/?$         members.php [L]
RewriteRule ^membership/?$      membership.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$         contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^privacy/?$         privacy.php [L]
RewriteRule ^terms/?$           terms.php [L]
```

If I visit `example.com/login`, it loads `example.com/loginregister.php`.

The same works for `member/`, `members/`, `membership/` and `contact/`.

However, I have just added the rules for `privacy/` and `terms/`, and they are not working.

When visiting those two pages I see this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /privacy was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) Server at example.com Port 80
```

However, if I access them directly (`/privacy.php` or `/terms.php`), they load fine.

Why are those two rules not working?

Comment: Have you check with `/` at end of url? i.e. `www.example.com/privacy/`

Comment: Same result: `The requested URL /privacy/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: Try to debug by shuffling your rules, take this both rules on top and see any effect?

Comment: @Rikesh As if that worked... Unbelievable. I put them at the top and now they are all working fine - even the ones which are now at the bottom. Could it have been a whitespace issue? I have no idea... Thanks though!

Comment: No problem. I guess some rule must be conflicting others. So sometimes priority matters ;)

Comment: @Rikesh Stick that up as an answer and I'll accept it - not sure how much help this'll be to anyone else, but it worked for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mention in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798533/htaccess-mod-rewrite-not-consistent?noredirect=1#comment49646117_30798533), it will work if you shuffle your rules from bottom to top. Possible reason could be conflicting rules. So your .htaccess should look like,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^privacy/?$         privacy.php [L]
RewriteRule ^terms/?$           terms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$           loginregister.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register/?$        loginregister.php [L]
RewriteRule ^member/([^/]*)$    member.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^members/?$         members.php [L]
RewriteRule ^membership/?$      membership.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$         contact.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have RewriteBase, try adding "RewriteBase /" or "RewriteBase /your/rewrite/path" in your .htaccess file.

This help the webserver to know where to look for the file, and some times solves this kind of strange behavior.